# error on createEpicMiddleware

Tags: angular, redux-observable

When I call `createEpicMiddleware(epic)` function on Angular2+,
there is an error:

> "error TS2560: Value of type '(action$: any) => any' has no properties
>   in common with type 'Options'. Did you mean to call it?"

Even if using the sample official code on `https://redux-observable.js.org/` online live example, there is an error exactly same of above.
It seem to be error on `createEpicMiddleware` function's parameter's type error.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you been able to solve the problem?